# Angular Modal Form Returning doubled JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a working Modal and I am trying to replace the updateUser.pubData.firstName and updateUser.pubData.lastName values but when I change the values and click ok, the following object is returned to the controller (pubData values are duplicated, not replaced).

Any thoughts on what I need to do to replace the firstName and lastName values in pubData rather than have them be duplicated? Thanks!

{  _id: '55394b4e87fd7088751c4809'
 username: 'd',
 password: 'x',
 __v: 0,
 pubComments: [],
 pubData:
  { firstName: 'dan',
    lastName: 'darby',
    firstname: 'dave',
    lastname: 'deefe' },
 bookshelf: [],
 roles: [ 'admin', 'student' ] }

Controller Modal Handler:

```
     $scope.openUpdateUserModal = function (user) {
console.log(user.pubData.firstName);
console.log(user);
$scope.updateUser = user;
//$scope.firstname = user.pubData.firstName;
//$scope.lastname = user.pubData.lastName;
$("#openUpdateUserModal").modal('show')};

  $scope.updateUserInDb = function (updatedUser) {
console.log("updateUserInDb");
console.log(updatedUser);
$http.post("/api/updateUser", updatedUser)
   .success(function (resource) {
     $scope.users = resource;
     $("#openUpdateUserModal").modal('hide')
   });};
```

Modal HTML Caller Button

```
        <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" ng-click="openUpdateUserModal(user)">Update</button>
```

Modal Form

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="openUpdateUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="courseModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form form-horizontal" name="userUpdateForm" id="userUpdate-form"><div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input ng-model="updateUser.pubData.firstname" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{updateUser.pubData.firstName}}" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input ng-model="updateUser.pubData.lastname" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{updateUser.pubData.lastName}}" />
      </div>
  </div>
    </form>
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="updateUserInDb(updateUser)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript property / field names are case sensitive.
In your markup you are pointing `ng-model` attributes at `updateUser.pubData.lastname`, whereas I assume the correct property is `.lastName`.

The giveaway is `firstName: 'dan', lastName: 'darby', firstname: 'dave', lastname: 'deefe'` - notice the upper vs lower case 'n'

Comment: Thank you for seeing what I couldn't!